# Embedded Tomcat 7.0.99 is forcing default welcome files into context

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, web.xml, welcome-file

I am upgrading a Spring/Angular application from Tomcat 7.0.59 to 7.0.99. I am using an embedded Tomcat server and running the app from the command line ("tomcat7:run-war").

The problem is that default welcome files are being added to the context (from Tomcat.initWebappDefaults()). The Tomcat code is adding a *defaultWebXmlListener* in Tomcat.addWebapp, which adds a bunch of stuff, including "index.html", "index.htm", and "index.jsp". I want index.html and index.htm to be removed, but embedded Tomcat is forcing them in. My application's *web.xml* **is** being found, but the welcome files are being appended to the list, not replacing.

When I run tomcat 7.0.59 from the command line, it works fine and doesn't add the extra welcome files.

When I run tomcat 7.0.99 from inside IntelliJ using an external server, it works fine and doesn't add the extra welcome files.

Answer (score 0):

So two things: Tomcat 7.0.100 adds a (sort of) fix for this. According to [Bug 62755](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62755), a setter for "setAddDefaultWebXmlToWebapp" was added to Tomcat.java to prevent the default config from being added. (Problem is, I don't know how to set this flag in my application code).

My actual solution was to do some reflective meddling in the context, during the onStartup of my SpringBootServletInitializer.

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    //Remove the default welcome files that embedded Tomcat 7.0.99 adds because they become auto-concatenated to requests without a file
    try {
        final ApplicationContext appCtx = (ApplicationContext) get(ApplicationContextFacade.class, servletContext);
        final Context tomcatCtx = (Context) get(ApplicationContext.class, appCtx);
        tomcatCtx.removeWelcomeFile("index.html");
        tomcatCtx.removeWelcomeFile("index.htm");
   } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
...
private static Object get(final Class<?> clazz, final Object facade) throws Exception {
    final Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField("context");
    final boolean acc = field.isAccessible();
    field.setAccessible(true);
    try {
      return field.get(facade);
    } finally {
      field.setAccessible(acc);
    }
  }
```

This can also be done in a ServletContextListener.contextInitialized method.